# running sum & add value to first row only

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a ledger using MS Access 2010

I have the ledger report with unbound textbox to calculate the balance of each record include running sum for a calculation of 2 fields as below:

> [Debit] - [credit]

It's working good, what I want to do is to add the open account value to the 1st row only, so the calculation for the 1st row only should be like this

> [Debit] - [credit] + OpenBalance

then to use the 1st calculation for the other rows

but I failed to do it, any idea of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution for the running balance with the open balance as below:

1- is to have the open balance in a text box inside the report.
2- have a hidden text box as running sum over all, to have [Debit] - [credit] sum.
3- add another text box to have the result of [Debit] - [credit] then add the balance value to it.